# How to write the HTML code for the inline element showing an image for use in webpage?

Tags: javascript, unused-variables

I'm writing my first code in an interactive/follow-along program through Cengage (MindTap).  The program is instructing me to "write the HTML code for the inline element showing the sky image to use in the webpage."  I am supposed to create a variable named **imgStr** that stores this text string:

```
    <img src='sd_skyMap.png' />
```

Where Map is the value of the mapNum variable (there are 23 files titled sd_sky0, sd_sky1, sd_sky3 and so fourth).  It says to use the + operator to combine text strings together and to include single-quote characters within the text strings.

I cannot get the sky images to appear on the webpage to save my life.

I've attempted going through a tutor provided through my university but have still have no luck getting the image to display.

```
    var imgStr = "<img src='sd_sky0 + sd_sky1 + sd_sky2 + sd_sky3 +
    sd_sky4 + sd_sky5 + sd_sky6 + sd_sky7 + sd_sky8 + sd_sky9 + 
    sd_sky10 + sd_sky11 + sd_sky12 + sd_sky13 + sd_sky14 + sd_sky15 
    + sd_sky16 + sd_sky17 + sd_sky18 + sd_sky19 + sd_sky20 + 
    sd_sky21 + sd_sky22 + sd_sky23' + mapNum + '.png' />";
    document.getElementById("planisphere").insertAdjacentHTML() = imgStr;
```

Having inserted the code into jshint.com, it stated one warning and one unused variable.

(Bad assignment.)

document.getElementById("planisphere").insertAdjacentHTML() = imgStr;

and mapNum is an unused variable.

Comment: Is 'mapNum' supposed to be a variable or a string in the image name? e.g '<img src="sd_sky0mapNum.png" /> or a chain of 'sd_sky[NUM]' consecutively?

Comment: @seantunwin Yes a chain of 'sd_sky[NUM]' !

Comment: If you're hard-coding the values should you remove `+ mapNum` from the `src` string?

Comment: Well that would make a lot of sense... I will give that a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[InsertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) takes two strings as parameters.

The first parameter is the `position` which takes one of four static values.

The second parameter is your HTML string to be inserted.

An example for what you want could be:

`document.getElementById("planisphere").insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', imgStr);`

Comment: Thank you!  My images finally displayed properly.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems on your code, the first is you need to run trough the different image files and add each one separately. On the code you provided, all image's names are being combined as one.

The second problem is your use of the `insertAdjacentHTML()` function. The function expects as arguments the position of the new tag and the tag itself, none is being passed. [Check here](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) for a better explanation.

Assuming you have n images that you want to add as n tags, you can try something like this:

```
// variable to hold the total number of images used
var numberOfImages = 23;

// we loop trough all images, where i will count from 0 to numberOfImages
for (var i = 0; i < numberOfImages; i++) {
    // on each step of  the loop we add a new img tag with sd_skyi as source
    document.getElementById("planisphere")
        .insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', "<img src='sd_sky" + i + ".png' />")
}
```

If you use this exerpt as is, it will add 23 img tags to an element with id planisphere.

Comment: Hi Pedro,  I'm not actually sure how to add all of the files separately?

Comment: This won't work because you'll be inserting 23 `img` tags. The for loop can be used to build the string for the image name, but place the `insertAdjacentHTML` outside the loop. ... Unless the requirement is one `sd_sky[NUM]` per image.

Comment: I edited the answer to clarify some points, please let me know if I am still not answering what you need

Comment: So you were entirely right about adding each image file individually.  The images finally displayed!  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You were nearly there, just append `beforeend` using the [`document.insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

```js
const imgStr = `<img src='sd_sky0 + sd_sky1 + sd_sky2 + sd_sky3 +
sd_sky4 + sd_sky5 + sd_sky6 + sd_sky7 + sd_sky8 + sd_sky9 + 
sd_sky10 + sd_sky11 + sd_sky12 + sd_sky13 + sd_sky14 + sd_sky15 
+ sd_sky16 + sd_sky17 + sd_sky18 + sd_sky19 + sd_sky20 + 
sd_sky21 + sd_sky22 + sd_sky23' + mapNum + '.png' />`;

document.getElementById("planisphere").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', imgStr);
```

```html
<div id = "planisphere">
</div>
```